# How to empty the data inside tbody using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to empty the data inside `tbody`, I tried:

```
$("#detail_tbody").html("");

$("#detail_tbody").empty();
```

but the result is that the  current page is cleared.
When i click the next page,the data will show again.How can i empty all of them?

```
<table id="detail_table">
  <tr align="center">
    <th style="display: none;"></th>
    <th width="100px">1</th>
    <th width="130px">2</th>
    <th width="130px">3</th>
    <th width="130px">4</th>
    <th width="130px">5</th>
    <th width="130px">6</th>
    <th width="130px">7</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="detail_tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

The js is :

```
for (var i = 0; i < productTradeDetail_list.length; i++) {
  productTradeDetail_listobj = productTradeDetail_list[i];
  p += "<tr align=\"center\">" +
    "<td style='display: none;'>" + i + "</td>" + //
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.procode + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.proname + i + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.tradename + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.confirmatm + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.confirmvol + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.statename + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + productTradeDetail_listobj.tradedata + "</td></tr>";
}
$("#detail_tbody").empty();
$("#detail_tbody").append(p);
page = new Page(5, "detail_table", "detail_tbody");
$("#tradeDetail_pageLabel").val(page.pageIndex + 1 + "/" + page.pageCount);
```

ADD:I have two response,i need clear current data of response and show another when i change into next response.

Comment: Could you add the HTML to your question?

Comment: javascript operate only on client side until then the page is refreshed again.

Comment: In all pages you will have to run this code

Comment: @Justin the code was added

Comment: Create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem so people can see it in action.

Comment: And what is `productTradeDetail_list`? Please post ALL the relevant code.